# Am I using CASE WHEN Correctly?

Tags: sql, case, case-when

Edit:

Sorry I did not clarify in beginning. CompanyType is smallint, not null and TotalLicenses is int, null

Basically I only want to check that `TotalLicenses > 0 if C.CompanyType != 4`

I looked at a few reference guides and tutorials, but I couldn't find one that confirmed that I am using CASE WHEN how I intend to in this example.

I am trying to update the "Purchased" column to 1 when Expiration is greater than or equal to Today's date, DemoLicense is equal to 0, and TotalLicenses is greater than 0 if the company type is not 4. If it is 4 it can be 0

```
update WebCatalog.Published.DemoTracking
set Purchased = 1
from WebCatalog.Published.Company C
    inner join WebCatalog.Published.RCompany RC
        on C.RCompany = RC.Link
    inner join WebCatalog.Published.DemoTracking DT
        on C.PKey = DT.CompanyPKey and DT.Purchased = 0
where RC.Expiration >= Cast(GETDATE() as Date) and RC.DemoLicense = 0
and C.TotalLicenses > 
    Case 
        when C.CompanyType != 4 THEN 0
    END
```

Comment: So, if `C.CompanyType` is equal to `4`, the update should be done?

Comment: the update should be done no matter what C.CompanyType is, but if Company Type is anything other than 4, the update should only be done if TotalLicenses is greater than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that much different from the way you described it:

```
update WebCatalog.Published.DemoTracking
set Purchased = 1
from WebCatalog.Published.Company C
        inner join WebCatalog.Published.RCompany RC
            on C.RCompany = RC.Link
        inner join WebCatalog.Published.DemoTracking DT
            on C.PKey = DT.CompanyPKey and DT.Purchased = 0
 where RC.Expiration >= Cast(GETDATE() as Date) and RC.DemoLicense = 0
 and (C.TotalLicenses > 0 or C.CompanyType = 4)
```

Comment: This actually is what I was trying to accomplish. Nice simple solution. I don't know why I was overcomplicating. I just changed it so that it is
    (C.CompanyType = 4 or C.TotalLicenses > 0) so that it will check if CompanyType is 4 first and not bother checking TotalLicense if CompanyType is 4

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
and ( C.CompanyType <> 4 AND C.TotalLicenses > 0 
   OR C.CompanyType = 4 AND C.TotalLicenses >= 0
    )
```

which can be simplified (under the assumption that these two columns are not nullable) to:

```
and ( C.TotalLicenses > 0 
   OR C.CompanyType = 4 AND C.TotalLicenses = 0
    )
```

which, if `Company.TotalLicenses` can never have negative values, can be further simplified to:

```
and ( C.TotalLicenses > 0 
   OR C.CompanyType = 4
    )
```

Comment: there is no need for `C.TotalLicenses = 0`

Comment: @Bulat the OP says *"and TotalLicenses is greater than 0 if the company type is not 4. **If it is 4 it can be 0**"* Did you really downvote because the query can be somewhat simplified (and only if your assumption that `TotalLicenses` cannot have negative values is correct)?

Comment: [x can be 0] and [x equals 0] are not equal statements to me. in this context I suppose we can just ignore the "it can be 0 part".

Comment: I downvoted because it is incorrect, not because it can be simplified.

Comment: @Bulat You assume and suppose too many things. In what way is it incorrect? If the `TotalLicenses` has only positive or zero values, your query and mine are equivalent...

Comment: that is fine with me )

Comment: @Bulat The AND C.TotalLicenses = 0 is in a disjuntion with C.TotalLicenses > 0.  Ypercubes condition can be reworded as, TotalLicenses needs to be 0 or more, and if it is 0 then companyType needs to be 4.

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify in the beginning TotalLicenses is nullable, CompanyType is not nullable and they are both >=0 also CompanyType is a discrete set of integers corresponding to different labels. That's why I just say anything other than 4.

Answer (score 1):

1st I think the case structure varies between different DBMS.  So the following might not apply to you.

2nd When you are not specifiying an Else the case returns NULL.  Comparisons with NULL is also NULL, so the row will not be returned.  This means that you need a default case.

So you should probably write:

```
and C.TotalLicenses > 
    Case 
        when C.CompanyType != 4 THEN 0
        else -1
    END
```

Comment: This seems like the shortest solution given the way the table is set up. TotalLicense can be null for whatever reason, but I checked the table and there are no null values. What would happen if for some reason TotalLicense was null, would it return a value or cause the query to crash. I ask because this is going in a stored procedure.

Comment: @Adam No. I think you misundarstood me.  The Case construct would become null if there was no default clause.